# Unable to save redux state with redux-persist

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm currently using redux-persist to persistent data storage in my react-redux application. I have set it up according to [the documentation](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). I have tested it on a separate project with `npx create-react-app`. The persistent storage was working properly.

When I integrate it in my actual working project, the state saving doesn't work. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my store.js:

```js
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
    import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import rootReducers from './reducers';

    // imports for persistance redux state 
    import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
    import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web

    const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];
    const initialState = {};

    //config for redux-persist
    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
      }

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducers)

    function composeWithApplyMiddlewares() {
      if (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__) {
        return compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
      }
      return compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
    }

    const createMyStore = () =>
      createStore(
        persistedReducer,
        initialState,
        composeWithApplyMiddlewares(),
      );
    let persistor = persistStore(createMyStore());

    export default createMyStore();


index.js:

    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
    import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
    import RandomID from 'random-id';
    import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
    import 'plottable/plottable.css';
    import store from './store';
    import SignInContainer from './containers/Auth/Signin';
    import SignUpContainer from './containers/Auth/Signup';
    import ForgotPasswordContainer from './containers/Auth/ForgotPassword';
    import ResetPasswordContainer from './containers/Auth/ResetPassword';
    import CompleteSignupContainer from './containers/Auth/CompleteSignup';
    import UsersListContainer from './containers/Users/List';
    import CreateEndpointContainer from './containers/Endpoints/CreateEndpoint';
    import TestMessagesContainer from './containers/TestMessages';
    import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard';
    import initialize from './actions/initialize';
    import Setting from './containers/Setting/Main';


    const root = document.getElementById('root');
    const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
    const rand = RandomID(16, 'A0');
    localStorage.setItem('authStateKey', rand);

    const reduxOauthConfig = {
      backend: {
        apiUrl: 'http://0.0.0.0:4000', // TODO: Change backend URL here
        signOutPath: null, // Add signout path to destroy session token
        tokenValidationPath: '/svr/ping',
        authProviderPaths: {
          facebook: '/svr/auth/facebook',
          github: '/svr/auth/github',
        gitlab: '/svr/auth/gitlab',
          google: '/svr/auth/google',
          twitter: '/svr/auth/twitter',
        },
      },
    };



    const requireAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
      const state = store.getState();
      const isSignedIn = state.auth.authUser.isSignedIn;
      // const isSignupCompleted = state.auth.authUser.isSignupCompleted;

      // Complete signup first before user can do anything
      // if (!isSignupCompleted && nextState.location.pathname !== '/complete-signup') {
      //   replace({
      //     pathname: '/complete-signup',
      //     state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname },
      //   });
      // }

      if (!isSignedIn) {
        replace({
          pathname: '/signin',
          state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname },
        });
      }
    };

    const publicOnly = (nextState, replace) => {
      const state = store.getState();
      const isSignedIn = state.auth.authUser.isSignedIn;
      if (isSignedIn) {
        replace({
          pathname: '/',
          state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname },
        });
      }
    };

    store.dispatch(initialize(reduxOauthConfig)).then(
      () => {
        render(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
              <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUpContainer} onEnter={publicOnly} />
              <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignInContainer} onEnter={publicOnly} />
              <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPasswordContainer} onEnter={publicOnly} />
              <Route exact path="/reset-password" component={ResetPasswordContainer} onEnter={publicOnly} />
              <Route exact path="/complete-signup" component={CompleteSignupContainer} onEnter={requireAuth} />
              <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersListContainer} onEnter={requireAuth} />
              <Route exact path="/chat" component={TestMessagesContainer} onEnter={requireAuth} />
              <Route exact path="/add-endpoint" component={CreateEndpointContainer} onEnter={requireAuth} />
              <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
              <Route exact path="/:userId/setting" component={Setting} onEnter={publicOnly} />
            </Router>
          </Provider>
          , root,
        );
      },
    );
```

reducers/index.js:

```js
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

    import message from './message';
    import users from './users';
    import endpoints from './endpoints';
    import toasts from './toasts';
    import auth from './auth';

    export default combineReducers({
      routing: routerReducer,
      users,
      endpoints,
      ui: toasts,
      chat: message,
      auth,
    });
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I faced a problem like this so I made my own solution. Take a look at it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48800828/4468132

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I have checked the links you commented and there are impressive ways to handle persistent state.But I have decided to use redux persist since it supports encryption , compression , expire time setting and state reconciling.I have tested that library in the separate new project and it is working properly.Did you also use redux-persist?

Comment: nope. I made my own solution